# How can I find who deleted the role on "roleDeltete" in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm on v13 of discord.js and when I run this
`client.on('roleDelete', a => { console.log(a); });` it only logs `deleted: true` don't show who deleted. Can somebody help me about how can I find who deleted the role on "roleDelete" event ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use audit logs. The bot will need permissions though:

```js
client.on("roleDelete", async role => {
  let member;
  try {
    const log = await role.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ 
      type: "ROLE_DELETE"
    })
    member = role.guild.members.resolve(log.entries.first().executor)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err) // simply for debugging
  }
  if (!member) member = null
})
```

And now when you access `member`, it will show `null` if it couldn't find the executor, but will show the `GuildMember` who deleted the role if they were found.

Comment: I'm having the `log.first is not a function` error

Comment: Sorry, we need to access `.entries` for it to work

Comment: it worked I think but i wonder why member returns null bot have permissions you said in answer too but i really don't understand it why can't find member

Comment: Does it have "View audit log" perms?

Comment: yes it have adminstator

Comment: @Kaito try fetching all the guild's members and make sure you have guild members intent